webアプリケーション利用者が入力した英数字をURLパスにしたページを生成する方法
下記のようなものを実装したいので、コードと方法、仕組みを教えていただけますでしょうか。
できれば、JavaScriptを使用したいと思っていますが、無理なら違う言語でも構いません。
①利用者がURLで使用可能な10字以内の英数字を入力
②それをもとにhttps://example.com/mypages/利用者が入力した英数字
というページを自動生成
③利用者が今いるページから②で生成したページに移動
実際に実装している例としては、lit.linkでクリエイターがURL名を入力したら/lit.link/クリエーターが決めたURL名　
のページが生成されるというようなもの。

その javascript を UA 側（Edge/Chrome) で動かすつもりですか？それとも Web Server 側で動かすつもりですか？　十分にセキュリティ的考慮をしないと悪用されそうな気のせいがします。

掲示板システムとかブログサイトでの発言/記事の新規投稿みたいな感じでしょうか？ そういった方面で探してみては？

Node.jsを使用し、サーバー側で動かすつもりです。セキュリティとしてはマイページの所有者かチェックして、直接URLを打ち込んでも所有者でなければ編集できないようにするつもりです。
